# Create a one-time generation t4 template

Tags: c#, automation, t4

I've been all over the place trying to find a way to generate a file from a T4 template in my project.

My goal is to :

1. Create a template
2. Include it somewhere (I don't know where)
3. Do "New file from template"
4. Generate a new .cs file in my project from the template result

If you can guide me or share a tutorial doing that I'd be quite happy!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) you'll find Microsoft's T4 documentation. You'll need to be aware, however, that Microsoft's support for T4 is not that complete overall and AFAIK it relies on 3rd party T4 editors for creating the templates. Such as [Tangible](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/04/t4-editor-by-tangible-engineering/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already read a lot of this place and installed Tangible. I'm trying to find a way so that I can use a T4 template to generate a file WITHOUT having a .tt file in my project. If you can point me to a direct place showing how to do that I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice package on NuGet from Steve Sanderson called T4Scaffolding that does this kind of thing.

http://nuget.org/packages/T4Scaffolding/

If that doesn't work for you, you can roll your own.
To do this, you'd use T4's service API from a Visual Studio Item Template.

You can do this by building a small COM component implementing the IWizard interface.

Here's the interface docs:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233750(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233750%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Here's an example of creating an IWizard (not a T4 one):
http://blogs.conatural.com/2009/01/how-to-write-a-vs-2008-item-template-and-wizard-for-conatural-data-commands/comment-page-1/

Here's the T4 service interface that you can call from your wizard to run T4 on an arbitrary file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.vshost.itexttemplating.aspx

Use the following code on any handy service provider to get hold of this:

```
GetService(typeof(STextTemplating)) as ITextTemplating
```